# How would i move these tables from 3rd Normal Form into 5th normal form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-normalization

I believe that the below tables are currently in 3rd Normal Form, for the PHP framework i want to use i need to have them in 5th. Would somebody be able to give me some advice on how i can do this?

```
create table UserAvailability (
    Id int Identity(1, 1) not null, -- primary key
    UserId int not null, -- FK to User table
    AvailabilityDay Date not null, -- Day of availability
    9-10 bit not null default(0),
    10-11 bit not null default(0),
    11-12 bit not null default(0),
    12-1 bit not null default(0),
    1-2 bit not null default(0),
    2-3 bit not null default(0),
    3-4 bit not null default(0),
    4-5 bit not null default(0),
    5-6 bit not null default(0),
)


create TABLE User_Availability_Notes(
    Phone_Number    VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    User_Notes  VARCHAR(500),
    fk1_User_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE User_Details(
    User_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    F_Name  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    L_Name  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Email_Address   VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Phone_Number    VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Mode_of_Transport   VARCHAR(8),
)
```

Comment: Which fields exactly violate the 5th normal form? When you don't know, how do you know that it isn't in 5th normal form already?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's in 3rd normal form to me.

Comment: It hurts just looking at that mess.

Comment: I know that the useravailability table is in 3rd normal form, i am making an assumption the other two table are also

Comment: Philipp, i am not entirely sure which fields violate 5th normal form i am again making the assumption none of them are

Comment: 5NF can be great for developers to make anything dynamic but it becomes a nightmare later on to retrieve the data. For example your `USER_Details` table would need to be split into multiple tables to allow multiple Phone-Numbers, Email Address for the same user. Practically there is almost never a reason to go past 3NF. The higher NF it is likely that you will need to denormalize it to retrieve the data.

Comment: Thanks very much Sauce :) Ill have a talk with my team and see if its absolutely necessary

Comment: a) Your CREATE TABLE statements are incomplete. Fix that. b) Normalization is based on dependencies. Where are they?